# Resolving discrepancy in covariance function calculated manually vs in R?

Tags: r, var, covariance

I am trying to evaluate the following formula in R

[image]
where,
ni is the number of individuals on patch i, m is the mean of ni and N is the total
number of individuals.

However, when I manually calculate the values vs. calculating it using the covariance function in R, it produces two different answers. I am wondering what the discrepancy is and if someone could suggest if I'm using the incorrect covariance function, or anything else obvious that I'm missing.

```
nx <- c(1,0,3,2)
ny <- c(3,1,0,1)

mx <- mean(nx)
my <- mean(ny)


Nx <- sum(nx)


covxy.manual <- ((sum(nx * ny)/Nx) - my) * my
covxy.manual # Answer: -0.520

covxy.direct <- cov(nx,ny)/(mx * my)
covxy.direct # Answer: -0.444
```

As per suggestion, I tried spearmann correlation on a different set, but that doesn't match up either

```
nx <- c(3,0,3,3)
ny <- c(1,0,1,1)

mx <- mean(nx)
my <- mean(ny)
Nx <- length(nx)

covxy.manual <- ((sum(nx * ny)/(mx * Nx)) - my) * my
covxy.manual 

covxy.manual <- ((sum(nx * ny)/(mx * Nx)) - my) * my
covxy.manual 

Nx <- sum(nx)
covxy.manual <- ((sum(nx * ny)/Nx) - my) * my
covxy.manual #Answer: 0.1875


covxy.direct <- cov(nx,ny, method = "spearman")/(mx * my)
covxy.direct #Answer: 0.592
```

Comment: In the second, case, if you change the method, it is close `cov(nx,ny, method = "spearman")/(mx * my)#
[1] -0.5333333`.   also, according to documentation `The denominator n - 1 is used which gives an unbiased estimator of the (co)variance for i.i.d. observations.`

Comment: Where is x and y? You are supposed to find `cov(x,y)` not `cov(n_x, n_y)`. Also since you say `Nx` is the total number of individuals. Shouldn't that be `N_x <- sum(n_x)` since `n_x` is number of individuals on patch x?

Comment: @akrun I tried and updated the answer. But it still does not match up with other datasets

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, N_x <- sum(n_x)..I have updated the answer. The covariance calculated between two arrays right? So I think i is cov(n_x, n_y). x and y just indicate the two different species here. If not, what numerical values would x and y stand for?

Comment: Are you sure `N_x` is a sum of the values in `n_x`?  In most versions of the covariance formula, N would be the length of the sample vector, and not the sum of the sample values.  Meaning, `N <- length(i)` and so also equal to `length(n_x)`.  It may just be a coincidence that the measure taken in each sample of `x` and `y` is also a count.

Comment: Your function does not agree with theimaged formula. Perhaps: `covxy.manual <- ((sum(nx * ny)/Nx) - my) / my`